# Using the "of " keyword in OCaml

Tags: types, functional-programming, ocaml, lazy-evaluation, keyword

What does the `of` keyword do in these definition of lazylist and a function using the type?
Is it just a constructor which defines the type of `Cons`, so that it takes a `unit` and computes a `llist`, or is there more to consider?

```
type 'a llist = Cons of 'a  * (unit -> 'a llist)

let rec lnat i = Cons (i, (fun () -> lnat (i + 1)))
```

(The `lnat`-function takes an int and constructs a list of all natural numbers, starting from that input int).

Comment: https://cs3110.github.io/textbook/chapters/data/algebraic_data_types.html#variants-that-carry-data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `of` is just a way of saying "this algebraic datatype constructor is composed of ..."

But from the rest of your question, it doesn't seem you understand really well what algebraic datatypes and functions are.

> Is it just a constructor which defines the type of Cons, so that it takes a unit and computes a llist

Well, no, `Cons` doesn't take a `unit` and computes a `llist`. Rather, `Cons` is composed of a pair of `'a` and a function of type `unit -> 'a llist`.

`Cons` is what we would call `a lazy list` because it is not constructed unless you traverse it. This is a deferred computation.

> The lnat-function takes an int and constructs a list of all natural numbers, starting from that input int

Once again, no. `lnat` takes an `int` and returns a new `Cons` containing this `int` as the first member of its pair and a function from `unit` to `lnat (i+1)`.

This means that `lnat` is an infinitely recursive function constructing all the naturals from `i` to `infinity` but only if you explicitely explore `Cons`.

Example:

```
lnat 0 > Cons (0, (fun () -> lnat 1))
```

`lnat 1` being behind a `fun ()`, its value is not computed allowing your program to not run infinitely.